# An 'obvious' inequality in Mean curvature flow

Tags: analysis, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

My question is from the mean curvature flow paper by Gerhard Huisken. First $H:=g^{ij}h_{ij}=tr(h)$ where $h$ is the second fundamental form of the manifold. Then $A:=\left\{h_{ij}\right\}$.

It states that there is an obvious inequality by the Codazzi equation which is \begin{equation}
|\nabla H|^2\le n |\nabla A|^2
\end{equation} $n$ is the dimension of the manifold. So I try to expand everything out and make use of the operator norm. $$|\nabla H|^2=g^{lk}\nabla_l g^{ij}h_{ij}\nabla_kg^{pq}h_{pq}=g^{lk}g^{pq}g^{ij}\nabla_l h_{ij}\nabla_k h_{pq} $$ For the gradient of the second fundamental form $$|\nabla A|^2=g^{lk}g^{pq}g^{ij}\nabla_l h_{qi}\nabla_k h_{pj}\le ng^{pq}g^{ij}\nabla_l h_{qi}\nabla_k h_{pj}$$ I notice the inverse metric in $|\nabla H|$ represent a trace of $h_{ij}$ but the inverse metric in $|\nabla A|$ represent an inner product between two tensors. So  I don't know how to connect two magnitude.

Comment: Just some remarks since I haven't thought through how to turn it into a perfect argument. The paper does not say that the inequality you are interested in is a consequence of the Codazzi equation—rather it says that the inequality of interest can be **improved** by the Codazzi equation (assuming I am looking at the same paper). The inequality you are interested in I feel should be a ready consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. $H$ is the trace of the second fundamental form, which has a zero eigenvector in the direction of the normal to the manifold...

Comment: ... Expressing $H$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$ as a sum of eigenvalues of the second fundamental form and applying Cauchy-Schwarz gives $|\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i|^2\le n\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2 = n|A|^2$. I think the same argument works with $\nabla H$, and $\nabla A$, too. The last equality follows because one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is zero.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz I see, I didn't think about the eigenvalue part lol.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Let $B_{ijk} = \nabla_iA_{jk}$. We want to maximize
$$
f(B) = \frac{g^{pq}B_{ipq}g_{jk}B^{ijk}}{B_{ijk}B^{ijk}} $$
First, note that it's obvious that the minimum value of $f$ is $0$. Therefore, the maximum occurs at a critical point of $f$.

Setting the directional derivative to $0$, we get, for any $2$-tensor $\dot{B}$ and some constant $c$,
\begin{align*}
0 &= g^{pq}g_{jk}B_{ipq}\dot{B}^{ijk} - c B_{ijk}\dot{B}^{ijk}\\
&= (g^{qr}g^{jk}B_{iqr}-cB_{ijk})\dot{B}^{ijk}.
\end{align*}
This implies that there is a vector $v$ such that
$$
B_{ijk} = v_ig_{jk}
$$
Therefore,
$$
g^{jk}B_{jk} = nv_i.
$$
The last two equations imply that
$$
f(B) = \frac{n^2|v|^2}{n|v|^2} = n.
$$

The Codazzi equations were not used here. If you take them into account, you might get an even better constant. In general, an inequality like this is called an improved Kato inequality.

Comment: OK but how to relate it to the gradient of $H$

Comment: The numerator of $f$ is the norm squared of $\nabla H$, since $\nabla_i H = g^{jk}\nabla_i A_{jk} = g^{jk}B_{ijk}$.

Comment: I see the final question. How do you deduce the $B_{ijk}=v_i g_{jk}$

Comment: By setting $$v_i = c^{-1}g^{qr}B_{iqr}.$$ So there's an explicit formula for $v$. But I've done calculations like this before and know that you don't necessarily need the formula for $v$.

Comment: Oh so you are solving the $g^{qr}g^{jk}B_{iqr}=cB_{ijk}$. I understand now, thank you very much